# how to enable mcrypt in php5.5 with rhel6.5

Tags: rhel, php5

i am using rhel6 OS with php5
But i am unable to add mcrypt extension for php5.

Lots of Google but doesn't find any solution.

[root@lav6 modules]# locate mcrypt.so
/usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so
/usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so.4
/usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so

[root@lav6 modules]# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so' - /opt/rh/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2014 07:31:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `yum install php5-mcrypt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you install PHP 5.5 in the first place? Because the default PHP version in RHEL and CentOS 6 is PHP 5.3.3 and installing mcrypt support would than be as simple as installing the php-mcrypt package.

If you built PHP from source did you install the `libmcrypt-devel` rpm package beforehand and include mcrypt support in your `./configure` options?

The native way to get updated versions for some web development components is via the [RHEL Software Collections](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html/1.1_Release_Notes/index.html) which you can enable much more easily on [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) with:

```
yum install centos-release-SCL
```

But with regards to PHP that only gives you PHP 5.4.

A number of third party yum repositories provide PHP 5.5, such as [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) which provides mcrypt support in the `php55w-mcrypt` package.